# Custom grid empty

Tags: acumatica

Really simple yet infuriating problem.

1) Created a DB script to add a field to the database and published. 
2) Created a new DAC based off the altered table. 
3) Created a new screen and graph. 
4) Altered the graph to point to the DAC created in #2.

Problem: The grid is empty and I cannot get it to show anything at all.

DAC generated by loading from the database (no changes):

```
  [Serializable]
  public class INItemXRef : IBqlTable
  {
    #region InventoryID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Inventory ID")]
    public virtual int? InventoryID { get; set; }
    public abstract class inventoryID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region SubItemID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Sub Item ID")]
    public virtual int? SubItemID { get; set; }
    public abstract class subItemID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region AlternateType
    [PXDBString(4, IsKey = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Alternate Type")]
    public virtual string AlternateType { get; set; }
    public abstract class alternateType : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region BAccountID
    [PXDBInt(IsKey = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "BAccount ID")]
    public virtual int? BAccountID { get; set; }
    public abstract class bAccountID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region AlternateID
    [PXDBString(50, IsKey = true, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Alternate ID")]
    public virtual string AlternateID { get; set; }
    public abstract class alternateID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Descr
    [PXDBString(256, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Descr")]
    public virtual string Descr { get; set; }
    public abstract class descr : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Uom
    [PXDBString(6, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Uom")]
    public virtual string Uom { get; set; }
    public abstract class uom : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedByID
    [PXDBCreatedByID()]
    public virtual Guid? CreatedByID { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdByID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedByScreenID
    [PXDBCreatedByScreenID()]
    public virtual string CreatedByScreenID { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdByScreenID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region CreatedDateTime
    [PXDBDate()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Created Date Time")]
    public virtual DateTime? CreatedDateTime { get; set; }
    public abstract class createdDateTime : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedByID
    [PXDBLastModifiedByID()]
    public virtual Guid? LastModifiedByID { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedByID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedByScreenID
    [PXDBLastModifiedByScreenID()]
    public virtual string LastModifiedByScreenID { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedByScreenID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region LastModifiedDateTime
    [PXDBDate()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Last Modified Date Time")]
    public virtual DateTime? LastModifiedDateTime { get; set; }
    public abstract class lastModifiedDateTime : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Tstamp
    [PXDBTimestamp()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Tstamp")]
    public virtual byte[] Tstamp { get; set; }
    public abstract class tstamp : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrNoteID
    [PXDBGuid()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Usr Note ID")]
    public virtual Guid? UsrNoteID { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrNoteID : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region UsrTemp
    [PXDBString(20, IsUnicode = true, InputMask = "")]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Usr Temp")]
    public virtual string UsrTemp { get; set; }
    public abstract class usrTemp : IBqlField { }
    #endregion

    #region Noteid
    [PXDBGuid()]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "Noteid")]
    public virtual Guid? Noteid { get; set; }
    public abstract class noteid : IBqlField { }
    #endregion
  }
```

Screen Graph (only change was to the views to use the DAC above):

```
using System;
using PX.Data;

namespace PennAirSales
{
  public class INItemXRefBLC : PXGraph<INItemXRefBLC>
  {

    public PXSave<INItemXRef> Save;
    public PXCancel<INItemXRef> Cancel;


    public PXFilter<INItemXRef> MasterView;
    public PXFilter<INItemXRef> DetailsView;

    //[Serializable]
    //public class MasterTable : IBqlTable
    //{

    //}

    //[Serializable]
    //public class DetailsTable : IBqlTable
    //{

    //}
  }
```

ASPX (no changes)

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" AutoEventWireup="true" ValidateRequest="false" CodeFile="IN202599.aspx.cs" Inherits="Page_IN202599" Title="Untitled Page" %>
<%@ MasterType VirtualPath="~/MasterPages/ListView.master" %>

<asp:Content ID="cont1" ContentPlaceHolderID="phDS" Runat="Server">
    <px:PXDataSource ID="ds" runat="server" Visible="True" Width="100%"
        TypeName="PennAirSales.INItemXRefBLC"
        PrimaryView="MasterView"
        >
        <CallbackCommands>

        </CallbackCommands>
    </px:PXDataSource>
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="cont2" ContentPlaceHolderID="phL" runat="Server">
    <px:PXGrid ID="grid" runat="server" DataSourceID="ds" Width="100%" Height="150px" SkinID="Primary" AllowAutoHide="false">
        <Levels>
            <px:PXGridLevel DataMember="DetailsView">
                <Columns>
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AlternateID" Width="180" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="AlternateType" Width="70" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="Descr" Width="280" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="InventoryID" Width="70" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="BAccountID" Width="70" />
                <px:PXGridColumn DataField="NoteID" Width="70" /></Columns>
            </px:PXGridLevel>
        </Levels>
        <AutoSize Container="Window" Enabled="True" MinHeight="150" />
        <ActionBar >
        </ActionBar>
    </px:PXGrid>
</asp:Content>
```

This is so straight forward I cannot fathom why there is no data being pulled (can see data just fine in a generic inquiry), seems like it's something very obvious I'm missing...

Comment: Shouldn't PrimaryView="MasterView" be PrimaryView="DetailsView" ? MasterView is actually redundant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a view that is not a filter (PXSelect vs PXFilter)

Try:

```
public PXSelect<INItemXRef> DetailsView;
```

Comment: I actually had thoughts of that too, but then previewing the screen causes a nasty ASPX error to pop up witch I don't really understand:
Exception Details: System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

Comment: Try to drop the masterview since it doesn't seem to be doing anything (change your page primary view to be DetailsView.

Comment: This was actually the fix, my issue had to do with bad indexes on the NoteID field.